# Подскажите как вернуть на клиент данные введенные в form. ajax + node.js

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, express

Помогите, пожалуйста, вернуть данные введенные в форму обратно на клиент в #formOut. 
Клиент:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>


  <form id="myForm">
    Name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="name" value=""><br>
    <br> Comment:
    <br>
    <textarea name="comment"></textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
  </form>

  <p id="formOut"> </p>

  <script>
$(function () {
  $("#myForm").submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.post("/handler", $(this).serialize());
    $('#formOut').append(trHTML);
  })
})
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Cервер:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    path = require("path");
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));


app.use('/handler', bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

app.post('/handler', function(req, res, next) {
    // это обработчик на сервере, после отправки формы url заканчивается на "/handler"
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log("Cработал!");
    res.type('text/plain');
    res.json(req.body);
    res.end();
});

// ------ запустить сервер -------
app.get('/',function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/index.html'));
});

console.log("Запущен сервер, порт 3000");
app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: вы хотите вернуть обработанные данные или теже, что введены?

Comment: @C.Raf.T пока те же, просто для примера. потом там будут обработанные данные

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.post("/handler", $(this).serialize(), function(data){ $('#formOut').append(data);
}})
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает)